# Creating a viewcontroller and adding Labels and buttons of existing VC to new VC Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am making a `form builder` in swift and I want the elements like textFields, Labels, Buttons etc should be assigned to a newly created VC, either they should be copied or dynamically created in new VC.

Here is I am trying to get a subView to a newly created VC by clicking the `Save` button

I want multiple forms should be saved as I darg much text button labels to view it can be saved in a new viewcontroller , new VC should be created programatically as I click on save button. like this multiple VC can be created as I want much more forms and letter I can retrieve them by form Name in other TablView and then onlick a cell a relevant View-VC will be appeared with text button labels

```
@IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    let formFirstVC : UIViewController = UIViewController()
    formFirstVC.view.addSubview(getFormView)
}
```

Here is the image in existing VC I have created form in a Scroll view. Now I want there should be a new view controller in which all the elements textFields/labels/buttons should be generated as I have created in this form.

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162074/discussion-on-question-by-ios-developer-creating-a-viewcontroller-and-adding-lab).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**// Create an extension of UIVIEW**

```
extension UIView
{
    func copyView() -> UIView?
    {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)) as? UIView
    }
}
```

Then in ViewDidLoad of second view controller add this:

```
 let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,375,625));
 view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
 let label = UILabel(frame: view.frame);
 label.text = "test";
 label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
 view.addSubview(label);

 let copyView = view.copyView();
 let copyLabel = copyView?.subviews[0] as! UILabel;
 view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
 label.text = "abc";
```

This will copy the label. You can replace the label with text field, button etc.

Comment: Thanks for your time effort but how can I do this.. would explain more

Comment: Just copy the code and paste it. Replace the UILabel with Uitextfield/UIButton.

Comment: Ok let me know if you need any help

Comment: Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'copyView'

Comment: Try copy() instead of copy view